# access token for simple search using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read that the `search` endpoint needs a user access token. However it expires quickly, and I'm just doing .ajax() get requests like

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=new+york&type=event&access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN

without using any SDK, just retrieving JSON data.
I'm hardcoding a new access token every hour, is it another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it is by using the long-lived [User Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending) instead of the short-lived ones. You can generate a long-lived User Access Token by using your short-lived user token, your app ID and app secret by making the following call from your server to Facebook's servers:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

You can find more info about it in the link attached and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/).

Comment: thanks! but, do I have to hardcode it (every two month) after generating the long-lived one?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to refresh it every two months. That is the only option as of now. You can find more details on refreshing the access token in the first link attached.